# Control animation time (scrubbing) in QML

Tags: qt, animation, qml

I have a Qt 5.6 `NumberAnimation` (many, in fact). I want to control the evaluation time of them explicitly. For example, imagine that this is an animation program, and the user has created animation curves, and is now 'scrubbing' the playhead back and forth along the timeline. Whenever I get a new playhead time, I want to evaluate all animations to produce the value appropriate for that time.

From the Qt documentation, this does not look possible. The members inherited from `Animation` allow me to `start()` and `pause()` and `resume()` the animation, to `restart()` from the beginning or `complete()` to the end. But I don't see a method or property that allows me to control the time. However, I've found (through examples) many QML features that are possible, but not obviously documented. Is this possible with `NumberAnimation`?

If this is not possible with `NumberAnimation`, is there another way to do this? Some way to represent an arbitrary 2D path for the animation instead, and then evaluate the Y intersection at a given X coordinate along that path?

Comment: Numberanimation is inheriting "duration" from PropertyAnimation, did you try that?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Thank you for the suggestion, but no, I did not try that. The [`duration` property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-propertyanimation.html#duration-prop) controls the overall length of the animation (how long it takes to run from start to finish). It does not allow me to jump to time to 95% through the animation, then 94%, then 90%, then 25%, then 75%, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discovered via [posting on the Qt Forums](https://forum.qt.io/topic/65630/can-i-drive-the-time-of-an-animation), the solution is to use an [`AnimationController`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-animationcontroller.html) to reference and control the animation, setting the [`progress`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-animationcontroller.html#progress-prop) property—normalized in the range [0,1]—to control the animation time.

To control many animations at once from a single `AnimationController`, you wrap the animations in a `ParallelAnimation`:

```
AnimationController {
  id: controller
  animation: ParallelAnimation {
    id: anim
    NumberAnimation { ... }
    NumberAnimation { ... }
    SequentialAnimation {
      NumberAnimation { ... }
      NumberAnimation { ... }
    }
  }
}
```